# Add event listener to child movie

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, event-listener

I have a little problem in AS 3 and I hope you can help me. What I am trying to do is to add an eventListener to a MovieClip that is inside another MovieClip. Things are going like this:

I have ParentMovieClip and inside ChildMovieClip. When I load ParentMovieClip I would like to add an EventListener to ChildMovieClip so that when I roll over the mouse on the ChildMovieClip it will play some scenes from the ParentMovieClip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which handles the ROLL_OVER MouseEvent:

```
function onChildRollOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     trace("child roll over!");
};
```

You should add the event listener to the child clip when you loaded the MovieClip:

```
parentMc.childMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onChildRollOver);
```

I hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: I have tried that but is not working. :( Nothing happends when I roll over the mouse on the child.

Comment: Have you got any error messages? In the code just change "parentMC" and "childMc" to the appropriate name of your movieclips.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParentMovieClip.getChildByName("name").addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
```

or
    ParentMovieClip.getChildAt(0).addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider looking at Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE. This event will fire for ParentMovieClip when it is added to the stage, and you can use that to trigger whatever initialization code you need to run in the child movie.